# Hooking to XMLHttpRequest method to change options for all request

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I have some problems with a third-party component and the only way I can think of is to change XMLHttpRequest default behavior and set *withCredentials* to *true*. I just don't know which method I should use.

I have already tried *constructor* and *open* methods. The general code I've been using looks like this:

```
var oldOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(){
  this.withCredentials = true;

  oldOpen.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

I have also tried to set *Access-Control-Allow-Credentials*in response headers:

```
   <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true"/>
```

Comment: `I have some problems` can you describe the problems? you seem to have CORS issues, do you send all the appropriate CORS headers in your responses?

Comment: Yes, I have CORS problems. Requests are always unauthorized, since the they lack any cookie. I'm sending *Access-Control-Allow-Origin* in response headers.

Answer (score 0):

Overwriting constructor was what I need. To overwrite constructor you need to do the following steps:

```
var xp = XMLHttpRequest.prototype;
XMLHttpRequest = function (args) {
    var obj = new xp.constructor(args);
    obj.withCredentials = true;
    return obj;
};
XMLHttpRequest.prototype = xp;
```